# Behavior of . and , operators in Perl for concatenation and parsing

Tags: perl, parsing, concatenation, dot-operator

I was trying to play with the `.` and `,` operators in Perl and got something weird which I was unable to figure out:

If I run this:

```
print hello . this,isatest, program
```

the output is:

```
hellothisisatestprogram
```

What I could understand is that it is treating both the text before and after the dot operator as string and concatenating them.

But what about the commas?  Why is it getting omitted and not concatenated?

Comment: Enable strict and warnings (`use strict; use warnings;`) to get rid of the barewords-to-strings. Then, consider: `print "hello", "thisisatest", "program"`, *without* the `.` operator - what is the behavior of `print`? Okay, so how does this make sense in conjunction with the `.` operator? (P.S. For questions about a specific operator, consult a reference/manual/tutorial *first* - in this case, see `perlop`. Also look up `$,` in `perlvar` and `print` in `perlfun`.)

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Answer (score 3):

First period (`.`) is treated as concatenation operator. Subsequent commas separate multiple parameters of `print`. The result is the same - all parts are concatenated. If you want to print literal commas, enclose `this,isatest, program` in quotes - `"this,isatest, program"` to form single argument.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
perl -e 'print "hello"." this,isatest,program"."\n"'
```

Run above code and check the output. If it gives you desired output then I guess we have an explanation.